# Evil mode bindings for non-English languages

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

After years of Vim I discovered Emacs's evil mode and now I am utterly happy. And I'd like to use my native language in Emacs as well. I thought it should be fairly easy and someone probably have done that already and I've tried searching for "russian bindings for evil-mode" but surprisingly I found nothing.

And then I tried this:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map [ш] [i])
```

and of course that didn't work. Please help me to bind at least some basic motions. Otherwise I need to switch back and forth between languages all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Oh... wow! I don't have to do anything. It's already there. `toggle-input-method` and I can even use Korean. Yet now I don't know how to get back to default. There's `english-dvorak` in the list, but I don't want dvorak. I need normal US-keyboard input.

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html), `toggle-input-method` switches between no input method and selecting one.  The behavior you see indicates that you currently have no input method selected.

Comment: You can use `M-x set-input-method` to choose an input method (which can then be toggled with `toggle-input-method`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but you can use bindings from https://github.com/artempyanykh/evil-russian.

For example:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "ш" 'evil-insert)
```